# Could not find a function that satisfies the requirement findspark

Tags: python-3.x, apache-spark, pyspark

I'm using Spark-2.3.0 and I'm trying to install Findspark by using the command:

```
pip install findspark
```

But I get the following error[image]

If you have any Idea how I can solve this issue please Help. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I changed ly directory to  C:\Spark\spark-2.3.0-bin-hadoop2.7\python and then run the command:

```
  pip install findspark
```

by doing that the issue was solved!
[image]